# Using the boto3 library with IBM COS in Windows

Tags: ibm-cloud, trigonometry, ibm-cloud-storage

You provide python example code here: https://ibm-public-cos.github.io/crs-docs/python

As part of this, a Linux user needs to either use the environment variables show on the page, or set up the file in ~/.aws to hold the aws keys.

What is the analog for Windows (assuming this works under Windows)?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
 > dir "%UserProfile%\.aws"
```

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-config-files.html

Alternatively, if you follow the links from the link you provided younare taken to the boto3 s3 library which describes environment variables for setting your credentials: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, I would recommend one of two approaches:

1) Installing [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/install.html) which is the most popular way to get a bash shell on a Windows environment

2) Installing Ubuntu natively on your Windows machine. Starting with Windows 10, it is now possible to run a Linux kernel natively, **inside** 
a Windows system [1][2]. This is also referred to as "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows". There is a very [cool talk with a demo](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/03/30/run-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows/) about this.

Alternatively, you could continue to live in a pure Windows environment and instead [set up environment variables in Windows](https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html) for your Python application.

[1] https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/ubuntu/9nblggh4msv6
[2] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about